# How do I fix this npx create-react-app error?

Tags: reactjs, npm-start

This is How it looks

[image]

**When I gave "npx create-react-app my-app" this is what I faced.
Could'nt figure out any measures.
"yarn create-react-app my-app" - this didn't work either.**

```
Creating a new React app in C:\mern-stack-project\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\mern-stack-project\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\mern-stack-project\my-app\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\mern-stack-project\my-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
+ react-dom@16.13.1
+ react@16.13.1
added 1613 packages from 750 contributors in 216.578s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
```

***And my prompt had these comments for hours.***

I'll attach my screens.

My console stays like this and I had to open another window to execute "npm start"

[image]

And this is what I get after running "npm start"

[image]

Comment: I don't see any errors in here. It looks like it succeeded. What's the problem?

Comment: My problem here is, I'm not able to run "npm start" command as my prompt is the same for many hours. And I'm not able to start my react app.

Comment: What version of node, and npm are you running?

Comment: v12.16.1 - Node version and 6.14.5 - npm version

Comment: Hmm, I had a similar issue and what resolved it was updating npm and reinstalling npx. Have you tried this?

Comment: can you show the actual error you're receiving??

Comment: Yes, I have tried both. The Error I get is , "missing script : start" when I give npm start, but even before that, my console stays the same for hours with those statements like, ".......run `npm fund` for details"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong, here are some troubleshooting steps you can follow to see if it helps:

- Delete your node install
- Install again, but from the [official website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). Don't google random pages about installing node, only official site.
- Make sure your Node and NPM version are 12+ and 5+ respectively
- Get rid of your `client/` directory
- Finally try again running `npx create-react-app client`

There isn't anything extraordinary with these steps, I just don't know what have you done to achieve your current error, so I'm sort of giving you a baseline of steps to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your command prompt was suspended. Go to the Resource Monitor and right click on the suspended cmd process and click on resume process. Do this 2 times. This resumes the installation of the packages.